# How can I see logs from react-native plugins with JS log

Tags: android, ios, react-native

```java
@Override
@ReactMethod
public Object callback(ImageProxy image, Object[] params) {
  Log.d("Hello", "World");
  return null;
}
```

I made my react-native plugin to make logs with this code.
I can see the logs in android studios' logcat, but not in the console where JS bundler is running. So I need to check two consoles to see logs from JS code and native code.
Do we have a way to make native code emit logs to the console for JS code?

I've tried `FLog` from `com.facebook.common.logging`, but it didn't work in the way I wanted.

I've only tested with android, but if there is a sample problem with ios, please let me know also.

Comment: You should be able to see the log from JS in logcat. But you want to see the Android log in JS terminal?

Comment: @Joe199382 Yes, that's what I want. Is it impossible?